# dark grey color appearing in some random scenarios in the background of views in android

Tags: android, colors, background, view

It is occurring in random scenarios and some time its happening to all the views and some times for few among many.May be because of either memory or graphics issues.Any solutions please....

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me after I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S3 software. Maybe the problem it's the basic light theme that has a light grey color instead of white for background.

The only solution I found for that is to manually set white color as background of all the layout containers in my application.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same effect on a S3 / S3 Mini phones, to solve this bug just remove "android:colorBackground" from activity theme. My problem was that I wetted colorBackground and windowBackground together for some strange reason S3 applies both but with some alpha channels (my original colors does not have alpha) and when you apply 2 colors with alpha the color multiplies. I do a testing also setting color in a Activity and gives another color of background so just removing all colors Fragment Root layout + Activity root layout and setting only a windowBackground instead of colorBackground solves the bug for me.